# Vuejs v-for and v-if warning when showing data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

Im using laravel and vuejs in my current project. When I was going to render the data in my component, It shows my data but in my editor there is a warning 
and I dont mind it really because it works perfectly fine. I tried to fix it but I cant get the solution. Someone know what should I do?

Here is the warining msg.

`[vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for]
The 'rooms' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'.`
`

Thanks in advance!

Reservations.vue

```
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                        <form @submit.prevent="login" @keydown="form.onKeydown($event)">


                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Guest Id</label>
                                <select class="form-control">
                                    <option v-for="guest in guests" :key="guest.guest_id">{{guest.guest_id}} - {{guest.first_name}} {{guest.last_name}}</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Room Id</label>
                                <select class="form-control" >
                                    <option v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.room_id" v-if="room.status === 'Unavailable'">{{room.room_id}} - {{room.status}}</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>


                            </form>
                    </div>
```

the script below:

```
<script>
    export default {
      data(){
        return {
            reservations: {},
            guests: {},
            rooms: {},
            form: new Form ({
                guest_id: '',
                room_id: '',
                reservation_date: '',
                check_in:'',
                check_out: '',
                persons: '',
            })
        }
      },
      methods:{
          getReservations(){
              axios.get('api/reservation')
                .then(({data}) => (this.reservations = data))
          },
          addReservations(){
              this.form.post('api/reservation')
                .then(()=>{
                    alert('success')
                })
          },
          getGuests(){
              axios.get('api/guest')
                .then(({data}) => (this.guests = data))
          },
           getRooms(){
              axios.get('api/room')
                .then(({data}) => (this.rooms = data))
          }
      },
      computed: {

      },
        created() {
            this.getRooms()
            this.getReservations()
            this.getGuests()
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your logic to not use v-if inside v-for, you can do it in a compoted propery like

```js
<select class="form-control" >
   <option v-for="room in filteredRooms" :key="room.room_id">
      {{room.room_id}} - {{room.status}}
   </option>
</select>

data(){
  return 
     rooms:[
       {status: 'Unavailable'},
       {status: 'Available'}
     ]
  }
},

computed: {
  filteredRooms: function () {
   // will return [{status: 'Available'}]
    return this.rooms.filter(room => room.status !== 'Unavailable')
  }
}
```

Comment: It also gets me an error sir and it is not working 
`app.js:42280 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.rooms.filter is not a function"`

Comment: @Vince Is rooms in your data object like above?

Comment: Where do you fetch rooms from api, can you share the code?

Comment: No. I just make an empty object of my rooms variable. it is shown in my script sir. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Hmm, if you are looping over rooms you should make it an array

Comment: Ah! now it works sir! Can you explain to me why did you put two objects in the rooms data sir and why did you make it an array instead of objects? because when im getting data from database, im always using objects to put the data there

Comment: It is just for the explanation :) You can make the rooms object as an empty array, because you are looping over the array with v-for function, v-for should take an array in order to loop around room objects

Comment: so i should change the other variables to array sir like my `guests` and `reservations` variables?

Comment: Its like this sir `guests: {
[ ]
}` ?

Comment: No like ```guests: [ ] ```

Comment: Okay sir thank you about it. Starting now, I will use array in my data for looping. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```html
<option v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.room_id" v-if="room.status === 'Unavailable'">{{room.room_id}} - {{room.status}}</option>
```

By:

```html
<option v-for="room in unavailableRooms" :key="room.room_id">{{room.room_id}} - {{room.status}}</option>
```

Where `unavailableRooms` is a computed property like:

```
// other hooks
computed: {
  unavailableRooms() {
    return this.rooms.filter(room => room.status === 'Unavailable');
  },
},
```

That's it! Now your `script` section does the logic and your template is cleaner than before.

Comment: Not working sir. It gets me an error 
`Error in render: "TypeError: this.rooms.map is not a function"`

Comment: Sorry, you should use filter. Edited

Comment: Still getting error sir
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.rooms.filter is not a function"`

Comment: You should have rooms in your data to be available in `this.rooms`, how do you get `rooms` info?

Comment: What do you mean sir? Im confused in your question

Comment: What does `console.log(this.rooms)` say?

Comment: `{__ob__: Observer}` sir

Comment: Maybe sir. Should i make it an array? and put some value like status?

Comment: Yes. rooms should look like `[{ room_id: 1, status: 'Available' }, { room_id: 2, status: 'Unavailable' }]` and so on. If you fetch it from an API, check this

Comment: Thank you sir now I got it!